# How to get API response XML values in to variables in Jmeter tool for matching purpose with DB?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How to get API response XML values in to variables in Jmeter tool? see bold color values. my plan is to assign those variables in to  response assertion > 'pattern to test' for match with DB values(using Jmeter variable which comes in JDBC Response).

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Extract the value from XML using [XPath Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0), the relevant XPath query would be something like `//Product/Id/text()`

   [image: JMeter XPath Extractor Demo]
2. Once done you will be able to compare 2 JMeter Variables:

   - the one from the XPath Extractor
   - with the one from the JDBC Request sampler

     using [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

     - Apply to -> `JMeter Variable` -> Reference name, used in the XPath Extractor (NB: don't surround the variable with `${}`, just put plain text there
     - Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
     - Patterns to Test: variable from the JDBC Request (NB this time you need to surround it with `${}`, for example `${ID_1}`

       [image: JMeter Response Assertion on Variable]