# How to use Jmeter JDBC Request for For Dynamically changing Xml elements?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

According to my previous example [How to get API response XML values in to variables in Jmeter tool for matching purpose with DB?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27348/how-to-get-api-response-xml-values-in-to-variables-in-jmeter-tool-for-matching-p/27351#27351)

first time run API shown in Jmeter -> Xapth tester

[image]

this is defined in jmeter Pattern to test ${ID_1}   -  Value in DB Dynamically changing so **it will fail the result in API - Response Assertion**  on another day

[image]

Due to this in jmeter -> Pattern to test value should be ${ID_2} []

So How To Resolve this issue?

====DB table values shown below ===

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Contains` instead of `Equals` and then check for XML tag, in your case Patterns to Test:

```
<Id>${ID_1}</Id>
```